# How to select ASP syntax when creating new MVC 5 project in visual studio 2015?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, visual-studio-2015

As explained in title, How can I select Asp syntax when creating new MVC 5 project in visual studio 2015?

As I remember; in previous Visual Studio versions I could select ASP or Razor Syntax.

How can I do it in Visual Studio 2015 community edition?

EDIT: Actually This is what I would like to ask...When your are creating a new MVC app in VS2010, it asks you to select view engine.

But VS2015 doesn't have this selection. or I couldn't find it.

[image: View Engine Razor or Asp]

Comment: While I don't believe anything official has been stated, Web Forms (and it's associated syntax) is pretty much deprecated at this point. The new .NET Core library has no support for Web Forms, and since Microsoft is shoving everyone in this direction, it seems they intend everyone to also abandon Web Forms. My advice would be to embrace Razor syntax and start working with pure MVC. That's the only way your project will be future proof.

Comment: Not true. As I said, .NET Core *does not support ASPX*, and it's the foundation for what will become the full .NET Framework, as Microsoft works to make all of it cross-platform. They're silently deprecating Web Forms by simply not supporting in going forward in newer versions of .NET. You can stay on the 4.5 branch, and I'm sure they'll keep it patched for the foreseeable future to aid in transitioning to 4.6 and C# 6, but the writing is on the wall. Web Forms are the past, and it's only a matter of time before they're entirely unsupported.

Answer (score 0):

Visual studio 2015 no longer support adding aspx view.

https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/9201651-add-aspx-mvc-view-in-visual-studio-2015